# In Lotus Notes how can you change the date format?

Tags: lotus-notes, date

In Lotus Notes 8.5 how can you change the date format? I don't like 27/3/2013 and would like Wednesday 3, 2013 or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes doesn't seem to provide a way for an ordinary user to do this. This [article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095443) describes how to do it with Domino Designer.

The format isn't fixed as a search turned up various posts with different date formats. Some users suggested that changing the Windows Regional Settings will change what Notes shows. I tried this and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: glad not be using this garbageware anymore

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, choose 'Additional date, time, regional settings';  choose 'change date, time or number formats; under 'Language Preferences' 'Long Date' ignore the dropdown options.  Manually type d mmmm yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just changed my computer clock settings and it automatically updated the format in my lotus notes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your computer setting

- Time & Language
- Region (on the left side of the screen)
- Regional format
- Choose Recommended [English (United States)]
- 27/3/2013 changed to 3/27/2013

you can select different regional format as you prefer